# Arduino Serial parsing

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino sketch and I'm trying to change a variable with serial. I'm using some example code that I found on arduino.cc to start with. I'm trying to modify the code with an "if statement" to update a variable `timevar` with `integerFromPC`; the problem I'm having is if I type a number higher than 4 digits like 99999 it prints out the wrong data and the variable `timevar` doesn't get updated correctly? I'm not sure what to do?

```
unsigned long timevar = 1000000;
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // temporary array for use when parsing

// variables to hold the parsed data
char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
int integerFromPC = 0;
int ifpc = 0;
float floatFromPC = 0.0;


boolean newData = false;

//============

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("This demo expects 3 pieces of data - text, an integer and a floating point value");
    Serial.println("Enter data in this style <HelloWorld, 12, 24.7>  ");
    Serial.println();
}

//============

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            // because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
        parseData();
        showParsedData();
        newData = false;
    }
}

//============

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

//============

void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);


    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
    floatFromPC = atof(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to a float

}

//============

void showParsedData() {
    if (strcmp(messageFromPC, "set time") == 0) 
        timevar = integerFromPC;
    Serial.print("Time Set To ");
    Serial.println(integerFromPC);
    Serial.println(timevar);

  }
    //do other stuff
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`timevar` doesn't get updated correctly"? Does it not change, or does it change to the wrong value? If so, what value does it change to? Also, is it always with values higher than 4 digits, or is it values higher than 32767?

Comment: it dont get the right value. im not sure what conversions im missing here or how to do them yet. and you are correct it is with values higher than 32767..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `int integerFromPC`. `int` on Arduino is 16 bits. 99999 doesn't fit into 16 bits, so will appear mod 2^16 as 34463. Use `long` instead as you do for `timeVar` and it will be ok for up to +/- 2^31 .

Comment: i tried what you mention but it is still doing the same thing. the values im going to need to enter will be about 900000, what do i need to do for such a large value?

Comment: You will need to change the type of `integerFromPC` to `long` (or `unsigned long`, and change `atoi` to `atol` (the last letter there is an 'L' for long, instead of an 'I' for int)